# Do component variables bind to service variables automatically

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a service called StatusService and a component that imports it called ListItems.
StatusService has a "status" var in it, which contains the information for the list items within ListItems. (assume status has "pending" and "complete" styles - red border or whatever)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { StatusService  } from './';

@Component({
selector: 'list-items',
template: `
 <div
    class="first-item"
    [ngClass]="status"
></div>`
})

export class ListItems implements OnInit{
constructor(private statusService:StatusService ) { }
status;

ngOnInit() {
    this.status = this.statusService.getStatus()
}  

onClickEvent(){
    this.statusService.setStatus("complete")
    // no need for this.status = this.statusService.getStatus()
}

}

class StatusService{
constructor(){}
status;

getStatus(){ return status; }
setStatus(status){ this.status = status }
}
```

My question is, it seems when the service "status" variable is updated, it's automatically updated within the component (and it's view via ngClass), without me requesting an update within the component from the service with a getStatus() call.

Is it somehow bound to the service's variable or am I missing something?
I am new and trying to wrap my head around what is going on.

Comment: Please, check if your `list-items` component is used inside `ngFor` without trackBy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not what I'm seeing. I pasted your code into a stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r1tyjm

When I run and click the button, the component is not automatically updated with the service data.

If you change the component `status` property to a getter ... *then* the change detection will always get the updated value from the service:

```
export class ListItems implements OnInit {

  // Changes the status declaration to this
  get status(): string {
    return this.statusService.getStatus();
  }

  constructor(private statusService: StatusService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.status);
  }

  onClickEvent() {
    this.statusService.setStatus("complete")
    // no need for this.status = this.statusService.getStatus()
  }

}
```